# integral of Poisson Kernel P(x,y) (on the boundary) for a bounded domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations

show that integral of Poisson Kernel P(x,y) (on the boundary) for any bounded domain in $R^n$ is equal to 1 , in general

i.e
    How can I show

$\int_{\delta b} \mathrm{P(x,y)}\, ds(y) = 1$

Answer (score 2):

The Poisson kernel provides the solution of the harmonic Dirichlet problem:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\Delta u=0 \quad\text{in}\,\,\Omega, \tag{1}\\ 
u=f \quad\text{on}\,\,\,\partial\Omega.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
That is
$$
u(x)=\int_{\partial\Omega} P(x,y)\,f(y)\,dy,
$$
satisfies $(1)$. In particular $u(x)=\int_{\partial\Omega} P(x,y)\,dy,$ corresponds to the case when $f\equiv 1$, in which case the solution of $(1)$ is equal to $1$ as well, i.e., $u\equiv 1$.

Comment: Hi, sorry for a late comment, I apologize if it is in bad form to ask so late. However, I wanted to know, how do you deduced that $u = 1$ is the only solution to the laplace equation, given $f = 1$? Is it always the case that if $f = c$ for some constant $c$, then the soln. to the laplace equation with this dirichlet bdry cond. is given by $u =c$?

Comment: Dear @rubikscube09, I am not sure whether you have known the answer. The solution to the Dirichlet boundary value problem is unique thanks to the maximum principle.

Comment: @Steve yes - thank you for the reply. I realized that if you have two unique solutions then their value on the boundary is 0, and you can apply the maximum principle to see that the difference is identically 0 inside. I appreciate your reply!